# Visual Studio 2013 - Confirmation Message No Private Void

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-forms-designer

UPDATED CODE

```
    con.Open();
    int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if(rowsAffected > 0)
    MessageBox.Show("Record insertion succesful");
    else
    MessageBox.Show("Cannot insert a new Record");
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
```

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and have created a Windows C# Web Form Application and have been following a tutorial for adding a record to a database. It works but I want to display a confirmation message once a record has been created or edited or deleted.

In the form controls I have :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

In the tutorial it has protected void. I cannot add :

```
If (Page.IsPostBake == true)

Label1.Text = ("Your record has been added to the database")
```

As page is not defined. How do I output a confirmation message?

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@forename", textBox1.Text);
```

The full script :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace somecityform
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MY-PC;Initial Catalog=somecity;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into somecity.staff (forename, surname, office, email) Values ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "')", con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MY-PC;Initial Catalog=somecity;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"update somecity.staff SET forename='" + textBox1.Text + "', surname='" + textBox2.Text + "', office='"+ textBox3.Text +"', email='"+textBox4.Text +"' WHERE (staffnum= '" + textBox5.Text +"')", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }

        private void label6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MY-PC;Initial Catalog=somecity;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"delete from somecity.staff WHERE (staffnum= '" + textBox5.Text + "')", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are following a tutorial for WinForms. There is no Page in WinForms. Page and Page.IsPostBack belong to ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteNonQuery returns an integer value that represents the number of rows that are inserted, modified or deleted by the command. In your case you need simply to add

```
con.Open();
int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if(rowsAffected > 0)
   MessageBox.Show("Record insertion succesful");
else
   MessageBox.Show("Cannot insert a new Record");
con.Close();
```

Comment: You missed a couple of brackets. I have updated the script to show how I added your code. I get this error :

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll"

Comment: Try to look at the exception details. In particular to the exception.Message value. It could explain why the query fails

Comment: {"String or binary data would be truncated.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Comment: Something is too long for the size of the fields that you try to update or there is some other difference in the datatype. Your parameters are all of string type, your fields should be varchar or nvarchar to receive that contents. Sorry but cannot be more precise and now I have to leave the site.

Comment: I adjusted the length of one of the fields in the database. I see a confirmation message but the entry is added twice!